# Can an EAGLLayer have 'selective' retained backing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0

I'm making a painting program for iOS using openGL ES 2.0.  In my program, there's an EAGLLayer with a retained backing.  Each drawing operation 'sticks to' the layer, thus building up the user's painting.

Now, however, I need some graphics to appear on the screen without getting added to the painting--like a cursor that can be positioned by touches and effects the style of drawing but shouldn't actually become part of the drawing.

Can I do this by adding a second renderbuffer for the cursor in the same EAGLLayer or would it be better to have another UIView on top of the painting UIVIew?

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, there was very little down-side to having a UIView (cursor) floating on top of my EAGLLayer.  Added the UIView as a sub-view of my main view controller's view, not of the EAGLLayer and made sure that it was on top of the EAGLLayer.  Not sure why I thought this would be tricky, in retrospect!